# What benefit do clans offer?

Tags: code-combat

I've discovered the little blue and red flag icon that took me to a list of clans that I could join.  The list is awfully long and there are apparently private ones that require invitations.

Is there any reason for joining a clan?  Can you be in more than one?  Is there anything special for being in a private clan?

Comment: I would suggest rewording your question, or perhaps posting a second. You ask three seperate questions, here.

Comment: I don't believe we would rather see those three as completely separate questions.  They are easily answerable in a single answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you want to play with your friends, Clans give you a way to see their progress and easily find their profiles. You can also use clans to have private arena instances so as to play multiplayer amongst your clan members. Being in a clan also helps get multiplayer simulations for your ladder games from other clan members. Later there will be other features, like chat/forums and clan vs. clan multiplayer.
2. You can be in as many clans as you like, currently, although the more you have, the more distracting things will be as we add features like chat.
3. Private clans add a lot of other progress sharing features, so they are good for classrooms. They can also control membership more easily, since you can only join with the link, but all private clan members have to have CodeCombat subscriptions.